# Clicking on "print" does nothing

Tags: macos, printing

I've connected to a remote network printer and attempted to print something, but clicking on the "print" button does nothing, as if the button wasn't clicked. It doesn't close the window, doesn't alert about any problem, doesn't report a successful printing, and the paper doesn't actually come out. Checking the printer queue also shows no jobs.

Of course the problem may well be bad printer setup, but I don't see any report about any problem. Opening the printer configuration shows it as idle and ready.

Does anyone know how can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Is the printer driver the most upto date? Check by visiting the website of the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still couldn't find out how to troubleshoot this issue, but removing and re-installing the printer as a generic postscript printer helped.